# Problems with Bitgo api

Tags: blockchain

Anyone ever faced this, i don't know whats the problem, even the poor bitgo api documentation never mention it

{"error":"key count must equal 3","name":"Invalid","requestId":"ckyg2yaeq2i1l073c4rauc3q0","context":{}} Bad Request my wallet is:

this is the path
/api/v2/{coin}/wallet

Request Body schema

```
label   => 'WallZZZ',
    m => 2,
    n => 3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on BitGo documentation about [adding a wallet](https://api.bitgo.com/docs/#operation/v2.wallet.add) most likely you are missing the keys:

```
"keys": [
"585951a5df8380e0e304a553",
"585951a5df8380e0e30d645c",
"585951a5df8380e0e30b6147"
],
"label": "My Wallet",
"multisigType": "onchain",
"address": "ivxzn3bdn4uo",
"m": 2,
"n": 3,
```

Bitgo also gives an example of the JS request and `m`, `n`, `label` and `keys` are all provided:

```
  .coin('teth')
  .wallets()
  .add({
    label: 'My Wallet',
    m: 2,
    n: 3,
    keys: ['591a40dc422326ff248919e62a02b2be',
           '591a40dd422326ff248919e91caa8b6a',
           '591a40dc9fdde805252f0d87f76577f8'],
  })
  .then(function (wallet) {
    // print the new wallet
    console.dir(wallet);
  });
```